# c++ template argument deduction in function prototype. possible workaround in this case?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction

### Primer

I have a `Vector` class that does some math. Among other things, it has a `mean()` function that calculates the mean of all values inside the vector. It uses a `sum()` function that i added here just for completeness.

`Vector`

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class Vector{
  public:
    
    // ...

    T sum() const {
      T ret{};
      for (const auto &item : data) {
        ret += item;
      }
      return ret;
    }

    template <typename U = T>
    U mean() const {
      return U(sum()) / N;
    }

  private:
    std::array<T,N> data;
};
```

The `mean()` function itself has a template parameter so that a caller of this function has the option to specify the type he wants his result in. For example, if `Vector` is of type `int`, the mean could be subject to precision loss if it is casted to the type of the `Vector`, in this case `int`:

```
Vector<3,int> vec{2,3,5};
int mean1 = vec.mean();
int mean2 = vec.mean<int>(); // same as mean1
float mean3 = vec.mean<float>();
```

As expected, the values are

```
3
3
3.333333f
```

**This is all good. No problem here.**

### Problem

The problem i have is when i want to achieve the same with a free function (outside the class). My first, naive implementation was this

```
template <std::size_t N, class T>
T mean(const Vector<N, T> &other) {
  return other.mean();
}
```

But when trying to calculate the `float` mean, i'll have to always call this free function specifying both `N` and `T`, the template parameters.

```
Vector<3,int> vec{2,3,5};
float mean = mean<3, float>(vec);
//                ^^^i want to get rid of this "3"
```

### Question

I understand that template argument deduction does not work in function prototypes... And that there is likely no way of deducting the parameter `N` somehow without specifying it exactly. But maybe there is a completely unrelated workaround to remove the need of having to write out the `N` value when calling the free function that i don't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jarod42 and @HTNW i was able to hack it into a single function.

With `class U = void` and `std::conditional` it is possible to make the specification of `U` optional for the caller.

```
template <class U = void, std::size_t N, typename T>
auto mean(const Vector<N, T> &v) {
  return v.template mean<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<U, void>, T, U>>();
}
```

Example

```
Vector<3,int> v{2,3,5};
int mean1 = mean(v);          // 3
int mean2 = mean<int>(v);     // 3
float mean3 = mean<float>(v); // 3.333333f
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eWqdcE)

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that template argument deduction does not work in function prototypes... And that there is likely no way of deducting the parameter N somehow without specifying it exactly.

What?

> But maybe there is a completely unrelated workaround to remove the need of having to write out the N value when calling the free function that i don't see?

What about as follows?

```
template <typename U, std::size_t N, typename T>
U mean(const Vector<N, T> &other) {
  return other.template mean<U>();
}
```

that you can call

```
Vector<3,int> vec{2,3,5};

mean<float>(vec);
```

So `3` and `int` are deduced and you express only the returned type (`float`).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for pointing out the obvious. Don't know where my head was at... Played around with what you had, but my `typename U` was the last template argument. Of course when it's the first, the other two can be deducted from the argument that is passed to the function^^ small correction: `return other.template mean<U>();`

Comment: @mtosch: Notice that you need some tricks to have your default template value as `U = T` is not possible here.

Comment: yeah, just noticed that. here, the type *must* always be specified

Comment: @mtosch - "small correction..." - corrected; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might do the following to have both syntax:

```
template <class U, std::size_t N, typename T>
U mean(const Vector<N, T> &v) {
  return v.template mean<U>();
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
T mean(const Vector<N, T> &v) {
  return mean<T>(v);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f4ce8cd6b5dcebd)

Comment: what is the `int = 0` useful for here? if i leave it out i get the same result

Comment: I was mimic first you Vector  with `std::vector`, so have `template <typename U, typename T>` versus `template <typename T>`, leading to ambiguity, so use that trick, but with your `std::size_t N`, it already avoids that ambiguity :)

Comment: Would also be needed if you swap order of parameter `T` and `N`.

Comment: Ah, i see. is there a way to just have a single function? i guess you pretty much have to have two because `class U` must be the first template parameter and so you can't put a default type `U = T`...

Comment: @mtosch Set the default `U` to some sentinel (`U = void` seems fine) and then call `mean<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<U, void>, T, U>>(v)` or similar.

Comment: @HTNW you're right. with this it will work in a single function. i'll post my answer